# Eclipse hangs when trying to load org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt

Tags: eclipse

I have been using Eclipse Luna on Mac OS 10.13 for quite some time. It started hanging when I try to open the app. Eclipse hangs on "loading org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt". (See attached screenshot). 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKVzP.png)
I guess the problem is in my user account, as Eclipse starts OK with a blank workspace when opened from another user account.

I tried deleting the .metadata folder in my workspace and the .eclipse folder in my home directory as suggested in some other threads here, but this didn't help.

Any ideas what else should I clean or reinstall?

Thanks,
Irina Popova

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will stumble upon this.

Occasionally Eclipse Luna is going nuts about external monitor or multi-monitor setup. Crashes unexpectedly, after restart freezes on "loading org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" message.

Restart Eclipse without external monitors and reconnect them back.